# Switch a button's functionality each time it's clicked

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to alter the code given here: http://jsbin.com/iFesOvOs/1/edit in such a way that a single button would both start and stop the timer.

If the timer is stopped, it will get started n press of the button and if it is running, it will be stopped.

I need to do this because I am making a mobile site with lot of features and we do not have space to place an additional button.

What I have tried:

1. I have tried altering some attribute of the button, so that we can detect if the timer is running or not and take action as per that.
2. I have tried storing the timer's state in localStorage, fetch it back up and take action as per that.
3. I have tried keeping a global variable, but that too didn't work

Sometimes, the desired function didn't get executed at all (with no error messages) and sometimes, I got the error message of variables going out of scope - which I tried to rectify by use of global variables but only in vain.

What's wrong here, can someone help me out?

Comment: Could you tell me, why didn't the global variable solution work? I've just tried it in you example code, and it worked for me.

Comment: Can you show some code of the solutions that didn't work? They should work if implemented correctly.

Comment: Look at simple start/stop button functionality [jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/wX35A/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start(this);">


function start(b) {
  if (b.value == 'stop'){
    b.value = 'start'
    clearInterval(clocktimer);
    return    
  } 
  b.value = 'stop'
  clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 1);
  x.start();
}
```

Comment: Why do I feel like I just did his homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You can add class with name (start) to your button, add function that check if the class button name is start then start the trimer and change the button class name to stop, else when the class name is stop then stop the timer and change the class name to start.